# Extract unique lines from two sets of text files

Tags: windows, powershell, text, command-line, compare

There are **1 or more** text files in each of two directories, A: and B:. The aim is to print a **single** text file that contains **all the lines** that are **only** present in A:.

(Each text file may contain up to 2 millions of lines. If A: has 2 or more unique lines [i.e., only in A:, not in B:] that are identical to each other, then only one of those lines needs to be listed in the unique.txt output. The list of order [sort] is unimportant.)

Credit to [Lieven Keersmaekers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52598/lieven-keersmaekers) for the script below (clean and fast). Yet, I seem to got stuck with lines being truncated (at character 120; or wrapped) in the unique.txt file, instead of printing the **entire** unique lines **exactly** as they are present in A:.

```
compare -r $(gc C:\a\*.txt | sort -u) -d $(gc C:\b\*.txt | sort -u) | ? {$_.SideIndicator -eq '<='} | select inputobject | Out-File unique.txt
```

I tried to play with these to get entire, unwrapped lines, but no success:

```
Format-Table -Wrap -AutoSize |
```

What I am doing wrong? Either **Windows cmd line** or **PowerShell** would work.

Comment: following might get you started: `compare -r $(gc C:\temp\testfile1.txt | sort -u) -d $(gc C:\temp\testfile2.txt | sort -u) | ? {$_.SideIndicator -eq '<='} | select inputobject`

Comment: `C:\a>compare -r $(gc C:\a\1.txt | sort -u) -d $(gc C:\b\1.txt | sort -u) | ? {$_.SideIndicator -eq '<='} | select inputobject -` msg: `
The system cannot find the file specified.` windows cmd line.

Comment: Sorry, Powershell.

Comment: Try `compare -r $(gc C:\a\*.txt | sort -u) -d $(gc C:\b\*.txt | sort -u) | ? {$_.SideIndicator -eq '<='} | select -expand inputobject | Out-File unique.txt`

Comment: @Lieven Keersmaekers beautiful, thank you! maybe post your last code as an answer so i can mark it as best.

Comment: Done with disclaimers ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following might get you started.

**Short version (using aliasses)**

```
compare -r $(gc C:\a\*.txt | sort -u) -d $(gc C:\b\*.txt | sort -u) | 
    ? {$_.SideIndicator -eq '<='} | 
    select -expand inputobject | 
    Out-File unique.txt
```

**Long version**

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $(Get-Content C:\a\*.txt | Sort-Object -Unique) -DifferenceObject $(Get-Content C:\b\*.txt | Sort-Object -Unique) | 
    Where-Object {$PSItem.SideIndicator -eq '<='} | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty inputobject | 
    Out-File unique.txt
```

*Note that I can't shake the feeling that the comparison with `<=`can and should be handled better but I can't readily find a way.*

Answer (score 2):

Using `sort -u`, `bash`, and [`combine`](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/):

```
combine <(sort -u a/* ) not <(sort -u b/*)
```

The above assumes that duplicate lines are not wanted, and that the Windows file system is mounted on, or is accessible from, a Linux box.

Note that `combine` doesn't require sorted data, it can show lines from `A:\*` in any order given, and return *unsorted* output, e.g.:

```
combine <(cat a/*) not <(cat b/*)
```

...but this loses the property of not showing duplicate lines, if `A:\*` contains more duplicates of a given line than `B:\*`.

Comment: `combine <(sort -u C:/a/* ) not <(sort -u C:/b/*) > unique.txt` tried in command line, but getting error 'The system cannot find the file specified'. As indicated in the question, windows command line or powershell. Thank you.

Comment: Text files are in `C:\a` and `C:\b`. In Windows comman line I run `C:\>combine <(cat a/*) not <(cat b/*) > unique.txt` and I get `The system cannot find the file specified.` What I am doing wrong? Order is unimportant.

Comment: @user3026965, This answer exists because an earlier draft of the Q was (mis?)tagged `shell` (Unix compatible) instead of `powershell`.  Windows can't find `combine` because it's a *Linux* util, (available in the [*moreutils*](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) package, but not for Windows).   To use this code, the simplest method would be put the two dirs on a network share, and [`mount` them on a Linux box](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23032/mount-a-windows-network-drive) from which `combine` could be run.

Comment: thank you and correct. mistagged initially with `shell` instead of `powershell`. looking for a local/offline, windows command line/powershell solution.

Answer (score 1):

The most naïve solution that should be somewhat performant would be something like

```
$inB = [system.collections.generic.HashSet[string]]::new([string[]](Get-Content B\* | select -unique))

Get-Content A\* |
  Where-Object { ! $inB.Contains($_) } |
  Out-File onlyinA.txt
```

However, you'll be paying for having all unique lines from all files in B in memory. The only way around that (without having something much more complex) would be to filter the lines from A in batches and successively remove more lines that are in files in B.

Comment: `$inB = [system.collections.generic.HashSet[string]]::new(Get-Content C:\b\* | select -unique) Get-Content C:\a\* |
  Where-Object { ! $inB.Contains($_) } |
  Out-File onlyinA.txt`  getting 4 errors: At line:1 char:58; Missing ')' in method call; Unexpected token 'Get-Content'; Unexpected token ')'.

Comment: Sorry, should be fixed now.

Comment: thanks. no error msg, but hangs on without result. (100K lines in text files.) `$inB = [system.collections.generic.HashSet[string]]::new([string[]](Get-Content C:\b\* | select -unique))

Get-Content C:\a\* |
  Where-Object { ! $inB.Contains($_) } |
  Out-File onlyinA.txt`